# Número de "bound variables" não confere com o número de "tokens"

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz algumas alterações no script e está gerando dois erros:

1. Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /localhost/admin/crud/editar.php on line 33
2. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at localhost/admin/crud/editar.php:33) in localhost/admin/crud/editar.php on line 36

O que foi feito: apenas adicionei uma select para salvar os dados no banco de dados. 
O script:

```
    if(!empty($_GET['codusuario']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
    $stm = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE codusuario = ?');
    $stm->bindParam(1, $_GET['codusuario'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stm->execute() or die(implode('', $pdo->errorInfo()));

    $_POST = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if(empty($_POST['codusuario'])){
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO usuario (email,senha,chave,select2,pergunta) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'; //email, senha, chave, pergunta
        $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(1, $_POST['email']);
        $stm->bindParam(2, $_POST['senha']);
        $stm->bindParam(3, $_POST['chave']);
        $stm->bindParam(4, $_POST['select2']); //@new select box
        $stm->bindParam(5, $_POST['pergunta']);

        $stm->execute();
    } else {
        $sql = 'UPDATE usuario SET email = ?, senha = ?, chave = ?, pergunta = ? WHERE codusuario = ?';
        $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(1, $_POST['email']);
        $stm->bindParam(2, $_POST['senha']);
        $stm->bindParam(3, $_POST['chave']);
        $stm->bindParam(4, $_POST['pergunta']);
        $stm->bindParam(5, $_POST['codusuario'], PDO::PARAM_INT); //old number is 5
        $stm->bindParam(6, $_POST['select2']);
        $stm->execute();
    }

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: A linha 33 é a quarta da parte que você postou aqui?

Comment: @bfavaretto este código está trabalhando junto com o html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse erro acontece quando existe um parametro a mais ou a menos na consulta, no update:

```
   UPDATE usuario SET email = ?, senha = ?, chave = ?, pergunta = ? WHERE codusuario = ? 
                              1          2          3             4                    5
```

existem 5 interrogações  e 6 variáveis no `bindParam()`:

```
$stm->bindParam(6, $_POST['select2']);
```

Para resolver isso basta remover o sexto bindParam. o Segundo erro é a consequencia do primeiro

Comment: o erro é realmente este, agora na visualização da select se eu edita-la vejo valores diferentes que inseri.

Answer (score 4):

"Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /localhost/admin/crud/editar.php on line 33"

Sim, pois você tem uma query com 5 parâmetros, e está dando bind em 6:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE usuario SET email = ?, senha = ?, chave = ?, pergunta = ? WHERE codusuario = ?';
    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindParam(1, $_POST['email']);
    $stm->bindParam(2, $_POST['senha']);
    $stm->bindParam(3, $_POST['chave']);
    $stm->bindParam(4, $_POST['pergunta']);
    $stm->bindParam(5, $_POST['codusuario'], PDO::PARAM_INT); //old number is 5
    $stm->bindParam(6, $_POST['select2']);
```

Comment: Corrigi isto também, obrigado @bacco