# PDO erro com variavel em LIMIT

Tags: mysql, pdo

Em PDO hoje foi a primeira vez que tive que por uma variável no LIMIT, e estou recebendo esse erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
>   does not match number of tokens' in
>   nome-doarquivo.php:85 Stack trace: #0
>   nome-doarquivo.php(85):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   nome-doarquivo.php on line 85

A linha 85 é essa:

```
$sql2->execute(array(":idQuiz" => $idQuiz));
```

Meu código:

```
$perguntaQuiz = 2;
$sql2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM quiz_pergunta WHERE idquiz = :idQuiz ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, :perguntaQuiz');
$sql2->bindParam(':perguntaQuiz', $perguntaQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql2->execute(array(":idQuiz" => $idQuiz));
```

O que estou errando?

Comment: O `(int)` não é necessário.

Comment: Agora deu outro erro... vo editar

Comment: Assim como o @zekk disse, remova o `cast`. Caso realmente precise dele, que no caso não parece ser necessário, faça-o anteriormente fora do `bindParam`.

Comment: Não entendi @MarcelodeAndrade

Comment: No seu código exemplificado na questão, não há necessidade do cast `(int)` pois o php já interpretará o valor como um inteiro quando você fez `$perguntaQuiz = 2;`

Comment: Entendi, alterei, mas deu outro erro.... vo editar a pergunta!

Comment: Duplicata de [Número de “bound variables” não confere com o número de “tokens”](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17485/70) ?

Comment: vc deixou o código igual ao das respostas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro informa que um dos parâmetros informados não há valor a ser substituído. Vejamos:

```
$perguntaQuiz = 2;
$sql2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM quiz_pergunta WHERE idquiz = :idQuiz ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, :perguntaQuiz');
$sql2->bindParam(':perguntaQuiz', $perguntaQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql2->execute(array(":idQuiz" => $idQuiz));
```

No teu `select` você informa os binds `:idQuiz` e `:perguntaQuiz` porém só há um método `bindParam` declarado, você inseriu o segundo, dentro do método `execute`.

Altere para:

```
$perguntaQuiz = (int)2;
$idQuiz = (int)2;

$sql2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM quiz_pergunta WHERE idquiz = :idQuiz ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, :perguntaQuiz');
$sql2->bindParam(':perguntaQuiz', $perguntaQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql2->bindParam(':idQuiz', $idQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql2->execute();
```

Comment: Obrigado, agora da outro erro: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1' in arquivo.php:87 Stack trace: #0 arquivo.php(87): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in arquivo.php on line 87

Linha 87: $sql2->execute();

Comment: Você definiu o valor para a variável `$idQuiz`?

Comment: Sim, se eu tiro o limit, ou coloco um valor fixo no limit, o erro não ocorre. Ou seja, o idquiz ta vindo certo

Comment: De onde está vindo o valor de `$idQuiz`? É estático?

Comment: tenta dar um cast para int no bindParam do `:perguntaQuiz`.

`$sql2->bindParam(':perguntaQuiz', (int)$perguntaQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT);`

e verifica se `$idQuiz` e principalmente `$perguntaQuiz` estao chegando como int, se vier como string pode da esse erro.

Comment: Assim com o @NeuberOliveira disse, force o `cast` com `(int)` e veja se o problema continua.

Comment: Se coloc o int, muda para esse erro: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in arquivo.php on line 85

Comment: Editei que estão, faça o cast antes como havia comentado anteriormente.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade agora forçando antes foi que foi! Engraçado que são valores que vem do banco de dados, de um campo INT....

Answer (score 3):

Esse erro significa que voce não passou os valores para todos os marcadores.

```
$sql2 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM quiz_pergunta WHERE idquiz = :idQuiz ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, :perguntaQuiz');
```

Os marcadores são esses parametros que começam com :, no caso você tem 2 deles `:idQuiz` e `:perguntaQuiz` o PDO da preferencia aos parametros que você passa no `execute()`, como no `execute()` so tem 1 `:idQuiz`ele da esse erro.

Tem que passar os valors em um ou em outro.

No bindParam

```
$sql2->bindParam(':perguntaQuiz', $perguntaQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql2->bindParam(':idQuiz', $idQuiz, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Ou no `execute()`

```
$sql2->execute(array(":perguntaQuiz"=>$perguntaQuiz, ":idQuiz" => $idQuiz));
```

Comment: Também da erro.... Obrigado, agora da outro erro: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1' in arquivo.php:87 Stack trace: #0 arquivo.php(87): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in arquivo.php on line 87 Linha 87: $sql2->execute();